# Apache mod_rewrite manipulate query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How using mod_rewrite could i manipulate the query string variable?

e.g. i want the following query string:

```
?route=product​/product&​product_id=158?​ax13g76h
```

rewritten to:

```
?route=product​/product&​product_id=158
```

Basically i only want to keep everything between the 2 question marks. As soon as the second question mark is hit everything after is removed

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this case you can use this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} route=product/product&product_id=(\d+).*
RewriteRule (.*) $1?route=product/product&product_id=%1
```

And for all other

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)\?.*
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: hmmmm this actually did nothing

Comment: This didn't change url. This modify query string.
You can print $_REQUEST array and see difference

Comment: so how do i change the url as well?

Comment: Do you enable RewriteEngine (RewriteEngine On) ?

Comment: @Pjn2020 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1928/discussion-between-hadvig-and-pjn2020)

Comment: solution was to put the rewrite rule above some other rules that must have been interfering